# I have a list of string dates not being converted into real dates

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
   structure(list(date_mm_dd_yy = c("1/21/2021", "1/21/2021", "1/25/2021", 
"2/2/2021", "2/16/2021", "3/7/2021", "4/1/2021", "4/14/2021", 
"4/19/2021", "4/24/2021")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

when i run

```
dmy(Yes$date_mm_dd_yy)
```

or

```
as.Date(Yes$date_mm_dd_yy, format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

I get only some of the Dates filled, but I get 7 NA. I don't understand what the difference is with some that go through and others that don't.

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 18294, NA, 18446, 18265, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its due to a typo on my code and this question has been repeated multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
library(anytime)
anydate(Yes$date_mm_dd_yy)
```

also you say you do

```
as.Date(SRM_LATEST$date_mm_dd_yy, format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

shouldn't that be

```
as.Date(SRM_LATEST$date_mm_dd_yy, format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are in month-day-year format but your format argument to `as.Date()` is day-month-year.

This works for me:

```
as.Date(Yes$date_mm_dd_yy, format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

Comment: yeah silly mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
Yes$date_mm_dd_yy <- mdy(Yes$date_mm_dd_yy)
```

-output

```
> Yes
   date_mm_dd_yy
1     2021-01-21
2     2021-01-21
3     2021-01-25
4     2021-02-02
5     2021-02-16
6     2021-03-07
7     2021-04-01
8     2021-04-14
9     2021-04-19
10    2021-04-24
```